# How to get previous checkbox value and compare

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I am trying to create a checkbox limit based on a value change example: I have the following checkbox!

If the value of a checked checked box is different then the previous prompt an alert!
Some of the check boxes do have the same value. Not all of them!

Example:

```
<input name="" type="checkbox" value="here">(if this was checked)
<input name="" type="checkbox" value="here">(then this)
<input name="" type="checkbox" value="there">(would not allow prompt alert) 
<input name="" type="checkbox" value="here">(would allow)

<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox2[]" onClick="setChecks(this)" value="`key`=<?php 
echo $rspatient['key']?>" class="chk" id="chk<?php echo $a++?>" />
```

I have code that limits the number of checkboxes but I'm not sure how to compare previous values to the selected.

Comment: Uh-oh, did jQuery also take over Java?

Comment: I don't see anything in your question that remotely suggests that Java is involved. JavaScript, yes, but Java, where? What am I missing? You wouldn't be confusing the two would you?

Comment: @Rob W, yup, that's the `j` means, it's short for `javaQuery`, :)

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels See tags (or wait a few seconds, and see revision history, because of the pending edit).

Comment: Why was the jQuery tag removed in the edit? Edit: nevermind, it's fixed again

Comment: just store the previous value in a local array mapped to associated checkboxes and compare    `var previousValues = [[1, true], [2, false]]`

Comment: could you elaborate on how to connect this to my checkbox! if i can store the previous value i can do it from there! @pixelbobby

Comment: see you you can use some checkbox fun for help: http://jsfiddle.net/h682v/3/

Comment: SO, what you really want is to limit to only once, checking a checkbox with a given value?  OR do you mean ONLY IF the immediately preceeding checkbox is the same it should be disallowed? OR if they check on checkbox, they all have to match that one - I seek clarification.

Comment: If the next checkbox has the same value allow else alart! @MarkSchultheiss

Comment: and thanks for the link! note When page is loaded no checkbox is checked @MarkSchultheiss

Comment: You can check obj.getAttribute('checked') against obj.checked. obj.getAttribute('checked') -- old value, used for form.reset(), obj.checked -- current value

Comment: browser keeps original value in DOM tag attributues for any input and current values in DOM properties like value/checked/selectedIndex. You can use tag attributes to get original value and properties to check current one. Even more if you will change tag attribute you will change default value for form.reset

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to make use of the `prev()` and `next()` jQuery functions. I don't understand well enough what you want to do, but something like `$(':checkbox').change(function() { $(this).prev(); //this references the previous sibling })` would get you started

Maybe something like

```
$('input:checkbox').change(function() {
    if ($(this).attr('checked') && $(this).prev().attr('checked') && $(this).attr('value') != $(this).prev().attr('value')) {
         alert('you can't do that');
    }
});
```

But like I said, i don't know what you're trying to do

Comment: create a if statement function setChecks(obj){d=document.getElementByclass(chk)  If(d.value!=d.value) {obj.checked=false alert('you may only choose options from the same dist!') } something like this obviously this will not work

Comment: You create an if statement. Your question isn't clear enough and has dead code in it.

Comment: @dcpomero, upvoated your answer for the justice.
Tyler, come on, this answer is what you need. Please, state your questions more precise to get better answers.

Comment: Im not sure what is confusing please ask me to elaborate somewhere im giving all the details i can think of. I did not mean to word that to ask you to do it! im confused how to form the if statement! @dcpomero

Comment: Note that `$('input:checkbox')` is prefered over  `$(':checkbox')`.  They both evaluate to `$('input[type=checkbox]')` however but the "input" is desired so it only gets the inputs and does not use the universal '*" when the form of `$(':checkbox')` is used which equates to `$('*:checkbox')`

Comment: @dcpomero this kinda worked but my problem is the .prev() if i start with the lst checkbox and work forward i never get the prompt

Comment: I updated my answer. the if statement says "if you check me, and the element prior to me is checked, AND we have different values, alert". Is that what you want?